# Google Structured Data Testing Tool fails to validate type as an alias of @type in JSON-LD with schema.org context

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

If you use e.g. [lanthaler/JsonLD](https://github.com/lanthaler/JsonLD) to compact JSON-LD data with `schema.org` context, you will notice that `@type` keyword is replaced with an alias `type` in the output, which makes sense given that

> Schema.org recently added a keyword alias from @type to just type

The problem is that Google's [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) fails to recognize this alias. Here's a simple example to demonstrate this (try replacing `type` with `@type`, and it will pass validation)

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "type": "Product",
    "name": "SomeName"
}
```

Which raises a few questions:

1. Does the fact that testing tool cannot validate this valid markup mean google will ignore it, and it will not affect display in search results?
2. If so, is there a way to force `lanthaler/JsonLD` to avoid replacing `@type` with `type` during compaction (ideally without any other side-effects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question: yes, by using a different context. For instance the following:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/"
  }
}
```

This [context ends up in the result](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/jsonld/playground/?json-ld=%7B%0A%20%20%22%40type%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FProduct%22%2C%0A%20%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%3A%20%22SomeName%22%0A%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%0A%20%20%22%40context%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22%40vocab%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D&startTab=tab-compacted) but that is fine as the SDTT is able to process this.